# Nmap how to split and filter this(regex)?

Tags: regex, nmap

I think i need a regex code to filter nmap output.txt
I use a tool called: Word List Updater 2.7
so this is the output: http://pastebin.com/HwgiVHDA

I want to filter,remove duplicates and look like this, uff sorry for my bad english
5.2.128.130:3391
5.2.132.8:3389

and then without port:

1.179.133.46
1.186.40.82

This should work on Windows.

Comment: Please stop posting answers that shouldn't even be comments. Edit your question to make it clear that you are using Windows. And install Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

With port included:

`cat pastebin.txt | awk '/Ports:/ { printf $2":"; print $5 }  ' | sed ' s@/@#@pg ' | awk -F# '{print $1}' | uniq`

5.2.128.20:3389
5.2.128.130:3389
5.2.128.138:3389
5.2.128.158:3389

Without port included:

`cat pastebin.txt | awk ' {print $2 } ' | uniq`

5.2.128.20
5.2.128.130
5.2.128.138
5.2.128.158